# Get Gremlin query as a String and execute it in java without submitting it to the GremlinServer

Tags: java, gremlin, gremlin-server

I have a Gremlin query in the String format (for example "g.V()"). I want to execute this String without submitting it to the GremlinServer.

I use the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute Gremlin string directly in [GremlinGroovyScriptEngine](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/engine/GremlinExecutor.html) or through the [GremlinExecutor](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/engine/GremlinExecutor.html) (which just passes the string to the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` but has some additional features to it). Simple pass the Gremlin string to the appropriate `eval()` method and get back a result from that script evaluation. That's basically what Gremlin Server does internally.

You will likely need the `gremlin-groovy` dependency rather than `gremlin-driver`.

Comment: I don't know how to build or create GremlinExecutor, could you give me a java example for doing this and executing the query "g.V()"?

Comment: Both classes use a simple Builder pattern. Calling the `build()` method on either class will give you a `Builder` object where you can set additional construction configurations and then when done, just call `create()` on the builder. At the most simple level, just call `build().create()` on either class (maybe just use `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` first until you determine your exact needs).

Comment: I used this code and it works correctly:  

ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();

Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();

bindings.put("g", graph.traversal());

engine.eval("g.V()", bindings);

Is it ok?

Comment: Can you say how to set graph config in your solution?

Comment: @stephenmallette I use GremlinExecutor to do this. (basically convert the gremlin query string to a java class). What **i think** I am seeing is that creating the compilationUnit (GroovyClassLoader::doParseClass) takes a long time the first time. This is through the parseClass method in the GremlinGroovyScriptEngine. From the second time onwards we see a real improvement as we cache the class. Just wondering if I could get some pointers on how I could address this

Comment: There isn't much you can do except parameterize your traversals so that they hit the cache on future operations. You can't avoid compilation if you use the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine`. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#parameterized-scripts

Answer (score 2):

Adding a 'complete' example based on stephen answer+comment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
    Configuration c = graph.configuration();
    GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();

    // Creating graph
    Vertex marko = g.addV("person").property("name","marko").property("age",29).next();
    Vertex lop = g.addV("software").property("name","lop").property("lang","java").next();
    g.addE("created").from(marko).to(lop).property("weight",0.6d).iterate();
    g.io("test.xml").write().iterate(); // saving to file

    //standard query
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> javaQueryResult = g.V().hasLabel("person").valueMap();

    // preparing GremlinExecutor
    ConcurrentBindings b = new ConcurrentBindings();
    b.putIfAbsent("g", g);

    GremlinExecutor ge = GremlinExecutor.build().evaluationTimeout(15000L).globalBindings(b).create();

    CompletableFuture<Object> evalResult = ge.eval("g.V().hasLabel('person').valueMap()");
    GraphTraversal actualResult = (GraphTraversal) evalResult.get();
}
```

Simple debugging app to check how results evaluated from string compare to standard queries.

Using maven dependencies `tinkergraph-gremlin` `gremlin-core` `gremlin-groovy`, version 3.4.6