# Calling a method of Java from R

Tags: java, r

trying to call Java methods from R. I have written Java code for Java-Gremlin interface, which worked well. But now I want to Call the methods to R, so in return I'll get output data from gremlin queries and I can analyse the data. But in '.jcall()' command in R, getting error and hence unable to call the method in R.
The following is the java code which have written.

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph;

public class TinkerGraphTest2 {

    TinkerGraph tg = null;
    GraphTraversalSource g = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TinkerGraph tg = TinkerGraph.open() ;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Eclipse");
        try
        {
            GraphTraversalSource g = tg.traversal();
            g.io("D:\\PID\\data\\air-routes.xml").read().iterate();
            
            
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
    }
    
    public String getDallasRoutes(String country) {
        Long n = g.V().has("code",country).out().count().next();
        return("There are " + n + " routes from" +  country);
    }

    public Map<?, ?> getDetailsofAirports() {
        Map<?,?> aus = g.V().has("code","AUS").valueMap().next();
        System.out.println(aus.toString());
        
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List city = (List)(aus.get("city"));
        System.out.println("The AUS airport is in " + city.get(0));
        
        aus.forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ": Value: " + v));
        return aus;
        
    }
    
}
```

This code worked well and getting expected output.
R code to call method getDallasRoutes().Getting error in '.jcall()'

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
cl_path="....."
.jaddClassPath(cl_path)
test=.jnew("TinkerGraphTest2")
x=.jcall(test,returnSig = "S",method="getDallasRoutes","AUS")

##Error in .jcall(test, returnSig = "S", method = "getDallasRoutes", "AUS") : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource

#tried another command also 
p=J("TinkerGraphTest2","getDallasRoutes","AUS")
#Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Could you suggest me any solutions? It would be of great help!

Comment: I think there are some missing libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource$GraphTraversalSourceStub'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524089/how-to-fix-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-process)